# My code receives the error "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Tags: java, android, imageview

As the title reads, I am getting this error in my LogCat when I run my app. This is the code written after which the error occured:

```
public void coinAnim1() {

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayoutid);
    ImageView coin1 = new ImageView(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 40);
    params.leftMargin = 50;

    coin1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coinid);

    Animation coinFall1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.coinanimation);
    coin1.startAnimation(coinFall1);

    rl.addView(coin1, params);

}

public void coinAnim2() {

    RelativeLayout rl2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayoutid);
    ImageView coin2 = new ImageView(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 40);
    params2.leftMargin = 50;

    coin2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coin2id);

    Animation coinFall1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.coinanimation);
    coin2.startAnimation(coinFall1);

    rl2.addView(coin2, params2);
}
```

LogCat says the line "rl.addView(coin1, params);" specifically causes the error.Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? There are similar questions, but as I am new to coding I don't know how to adapt the answers for my problem.

Any help is appreciated.

PROBLEM SOLVED:

Ashishduh solved the problem by replacing the line:

```
rl.addView(coin1, params);
```

With the line:

```
coin1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope this helps someone! Thanks ashi <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The View `coin1` already has a parent (the RelativeLayout that you inflated).  You can't assign it to another parent without removing it from that RelativeLayout.

I think what you're trying to do is modify the LayoutParams of coin1.  Instead of doing this: `rl.addView(coin1, params);` you need to just set the layoutparams like this `coin1.setLayoutParams(params);`

Comment: But what does that mean! As I say, I'm new to coding, so all this "parent" and "assign" doesn't yet make any sense to me :(

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by adding it to the RelativeLayout?  It already exists in your layout so there's no need to add it again.

Comment: The margin's currently set at 50 just for testing, but later I will change the margin value to a variable, which changes over time. From what I understand, all this RelativeLayout and Layoutparams business is necessary to be able to change the margin/x-position of a view in an XML RelativeLayout.

Comment: In other words (I think what @ashishduh is getting at), the fact that findViewById can succeed when searching for the ImageView (id = R.id.coinid) means that that ImageView is already part of a layout (that layout being the parent) and is already instantiated.  Your intention with adding the imageview to the layout is to add a new image, in which case you want to add a "new ImageView()" setting the source to the desired drawable.

Comment: I've switched on "Mark Occurences", but coin1 isn't used anywhere apart from this method. So how would I use "new ImageView()"? Would I just remove "this" from the code? I tried this, and it just produces an error :(

Comment: Also, so if I remove the RelativeLayout line, what do I add the view to? Because I can't remove "rl" from the line "rl.addView(coin1, params);" without it erroring.

Comment: I think I've figured out what you're trying to do.  Instead of doing this `rl.addView(coin1, params);` you need to just set the layoutparams like this `coin1.setLayoutParams(params);` addView creates a *new view* which is not what you want.  You want to modify the existing view coin1.

Answer (score 0):

From ur code snippet

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayoutid);
    ImageView coin1 = new ImageView(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 40);
    params.leftMargin = 50;

    coin1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coinid);
```

u r creating `coin1` & `coin2` `ImageView` programmatically as u have already added those in `xml` either create those `ImageViews` programmatically  or in `xml`

Comment: See my "EDIT" - I've included some XML code. Also, thanks for helping :)

Comment: Also, what does programmatically mean? What do I do to fix it?